# reactjs material-table - add button at a row with action for adding new row under current row

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I use material-table and I would need to place a action button on each row, which would add a new row below it when clicked, with the proviso that it would be ready for editing.
[image]

So far, I have managed to create a button for each row that adds a new row below the current row, but the new row is not an editable one. Editing is possible only after clicking on the edit button. Could this be solved somehow?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-add-row-under-current-zeuoe4)

Comment: I think this might answer your question. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63328578/add-custom-add-button-in-material-table